# why values differ from select into query output and insert into query output

Tags: sql-server, xml

I executed the following query,

```
DECLARE @xmlfile xml set @xmlfile=' <Services>
<ServiceInfo>
    <ServiceName>AeLookupSvc</ServiceName>
    <ServiceState>1</ServiceState>
    <HardwareProfiles>
      <HardwareProfile>
        <ServiceID>2</ServiceID>
        <Profile>Undocked Profile</Profile>
        <State>1</State>
      </HardwareProfile>
     </HardwareProfiles>
```

'

```
  select 
    1 as assetid,
     (select dbo.ServiceMaster.serviceid from dbo.ServiceMaster where dbo.ServiceMaster.servicename=[profile].query('../../ServiceName').value('.', 'varchar(max)'))as serviceid,
     (select [profile].query('State').value('.','bit'))as state,
     1 as profileid
     into #temp
    from 
    @xmlfile.nodes('Services/ServiceInfo/HardwareProfiles/HardwareProfile')as Profiles([profile])
    select * from #temp;

    drop table #temp;
```

here servicemaster is a table which contains serviceid and servicename

```
serviceid servicename
1001       AelookupSvc
1002       ALG
```

the above query output is

```
assetid serviceid   state   profileid
1          1001         1     1
```

when i inserted the selected values to existing table it returns

EDIT: 
insert into dbo.AssetServiceState

```
 select 
        1 as assetid,
         (select dbo.ServiceMaster.serviceid from dbo.ServiceMaster where dbo.ServiceMaster.servicename=[profile].query('../../ServiceName').value('.', 'varchar(max)'))as serviceid,
         (select [profile].query('State').value('.','bit'))as state,
         1 as profileid
 from 
        @xmlfile.nodes('Services/ServiceInfo/HardwareProfiles/HardwareProfile')as Profiles([profile])
```

this query gives the

```
   assetid  serviceid   state   profileid
        1      1            1     1
```

Why the Serviceid value is resulted as 1 ? please help me to resolve this?

Comment: Is there any insert query?

Comment: The value of service id depend upon what you are passing in Where clause. what do you get when you pass [profile].query('../../ServiceName').value('.', 'varchar(max)')

Comment: Also are there only 2 records in table which you showed in your question

Comment: yes, in servicemaster table only two records are there.

Comment: when i use select into query the output came correctly. but for insert into query not. why this happen? is i missed anything